# AddEventListener to current target

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to add some mouse movement to a background image within elements in a grid -

this is my HTML, its repeated multiple times:

```
<div class="pure-u-1-3 grid-item" >
                            <div class="bg-img" style="background:url('images/blog/network.png'"></div>
                            <div class="blogInner" >
                                <p>SOME TEXT</p>
                                <a href="" class="lnk-a">Read More</a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

the following code works - but moves all elements -

```
const bg = document.querySelector('.bg-img');
const bgIn = document.querySelector('.blogInner');
const windowWidth = window.innerWidth / 5;
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight / 5 ;

bgIn.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const mouseX = e.clientX / windowWidth;
  const mouseY = e.clientY / windowHeight;

  bg.style.transform = `translate3d(-${mouseX}%, -${mouseY}%, 0)`;
});
```

I have tried to make the above code rso that it runs only on the hovered item as follows -

```
 $('.grid-item').mouseover(function(event) {

const thisitem = $(event.currentTarget);
const bg = $(event.currentTarget).find('.bg-img');
const bgIn = $(event.currentTarget).find('.blogInner');


const windowWidth = window.innerWidth / 5;
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight / 5 ;

bgIn.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const mouseX = e.clientX / windowWidth;
  const mouseY = e.clientY / windowHeight;

  bg.style.transform = `translate3d(-${mouseX}%, -${mouseY}%, 0)`;
});
```

});

on hover i get the error: 
**bgIn.removeEventListener is not a function**
I'm completely stumped - as the same code oustide the hover function works fine - can anyone help me understand whats going wrong please?

Comment: why not `this` instead of `event.target`?

Comment: Don't mix jQuery methods with some native javascript ones. Your `bgIn` element is a jq object, not a DOM element. So use preferably [$.fn.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to bind event. Anyway, you would have better to delegate event. BTW, it doesn't make sense to use `const` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use jquery events it should work rather than mixing native js with jquery.

```
bgIn.mousemove((e) => {
  const mouseX = e.clientX / windowWidth;
  const mouseY = e.clientY / windowHeight;

  bg.css({transform: `translate3d(-${mouseX}%, -${mouseY}%, 0)`});
});
```